# why Go ServeMux is also a handler

Tags: go

I can't understand why `ServeMux` which contains a map of entries that map a URL to a handler, is also itself a `handler`(it has a `ServeHTTP` method)?

Is it because we can use a `ServeMux` inside another `ServeMux`?

Comment: If it wasn't you couldn't [use it for a Server](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Handler).

Comment: yes, I forget that server will recieve a handler not a multiplexer. that's it, thanks.

Comment: but as a side question, can we chain `ServeMux`'s inside each other ?

Comment: Sure you can. You just have to wrap the inner one with [StripPrefix](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix).

Answer (score 1):

The [http.Serve](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve) method (and its cousins) take a handler as an argument. So if `http.ServeMux` weren't a handler, it would be impossible to serve it.

Further, as you guessed, making a mux a handler allows for composition. You can use one `ServeMux` for part of your application, and another one for some other part, if you wish.